# Passing foreign key id via url to imported csv file using django-import-export

Tags: python, keyword-argument, django-import-export

Im trying to import some data from a csv file to a django database using django-import-export, with a foreign key (location). What I want to achieve is, that the location_id is passed by the request url.

```
value,datetime,location
4.46,2020-01-01,1
4.46,2020-01-02,1
```

My urls look like this, so I want "location_id" to be passed into the uploaded csv file:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
...
    path('..../<int:location_id>/upload', views.simple_upload, name='upload'),
   ]
```

My view looks like this:

```
def simple_upload(request, location_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        rainfall_resource = RainfallResource()
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_rainfall = request.FILES['myfile']


        imported_data = dataset.load(new_rainfall.read().decode("utf-8"), format="csv")


        try:
            result = rainfall_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=True)  # Test the data import
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponse(e, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        if not result.has_errors():
            rainfall_resource.import_data(dataset, dry_run=False)  # Actually import now


       return render(request, '/import.html')
```

My ModelResource looks like this:

```
class RainfallResource(resources.ModelResource):

    location_id = fields.Field(
        column_name='location_id',
        attribute='location_id',
        widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Location, 'Location'))

    class Meta:
        model = Rainfall

    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['location'] = location_id
```

The manipulation works when I hardcode "location_id" like:

```
    def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
        row['location'] = 123
```

However, I do not understand how to pass the location_id argument from the "url" to the "before_import_row" function. Help would be highly appreciated:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will have to modify your `imported_data` in memory, before importing.

You can use the [tablib API](https://tablib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial/#adding-columns) to update the dataset:

```py
# import the data as per your existing code
imported_data = dataset.load(new_rainfall.read().decode("utf-8"), format="csv")

# create an array containing the location_id
location_arr = [location_id] * len(imported_data)

# use the tablib API to add a new column, and insert the location array values
imported_data.append_col(location_arr, header="location")
```

By using this approach, you won't need to override `before_import_row()`

Comment: Thank you, Matthew! Perfect!